# Generating random numbers from a truncated Gaussian

Tags: r, random, gaussian, truncated

Like in most physical problems, my case suffers boundaries, I thus want to generate (with R) random numbers according to a truncated Gaussian distribution.

The idea is that the mean value of these numbers should not depend on the boundary.
I already found the package truncnorm, but it does not do the job:

For example, here is the case of a Gaussian of mean 0.1 and width 0.1, but constrained between 0 and 1:

```
install.packages("truncnorm")
library(truncnorm)
vec=rtruncnorm(n=100000,a=0,b=1,mean=0.1,sd=0.1)
hist(vec,breaks=100)
mean(vec)
[1] 0.1289061
```

as you can see, the final mean is not the one given as input, I could have the same result by using the standard rnorm function and subseting the result.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so any idea or suggestion of further package will be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: You create a set of _random_ numbers. What leads you to believe that a _randomly_ generated vector will have exactly the same mean as you _think_ it should have? Plus, you are truncating non-symmetrically, skew in mean is expected. Width is called a standard deviation (see Wikipedia what that means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we might have to differentiate between mean values before and after truncation, and you apparently intend to control the observable mean values that truncated samples would presumably converge to, although `rnorm()` (and probably `rtruncnorm()`, which I do not know) expect "before"-means; while some statisticians at stats.stackexchange.com might provide you with a more watertight analytical solution, maybe some playful optimization could also help you find suitable "before"-parameters (you may have to adapt this code depending on whether the "before"-sd-parameter should also be modified):

```
myrtruncnorm <- function(n,a,b,mean=0,sd=1) 
    qnorm(runif(n,pnorm(a,mean=mean,sd=sd),pnorm(b,mean=mean,sd=sd)),mean=mean,sd=sd)
set.seed(1)
optim(list(mean=.1,sd=.1), function(x)
    abs(mean(myrtruncnorm(n=100000,a=0,b=1,mean=x[[1]],sd=x[[2]]))-.1))
# returns mean=0.07785390 and sd=0.07777597, let's test that: 
x1 <- myrtruncnorm(100000,0,1,0.07785390,0.07777597)
hist(x1); mean(x1) # Is "mean=0.1003832" sufficiently close?
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this what you expect when you truncate the distribution?

```
#Example
x <- rnorm( 1e7 , mean = 0.1 , sd = 0.1 )
mean( x[ ! ( x < 0 | x > 1 ) ] )
#[1] 0.128814

#Visualising
hist( x , breaks = 100 , xlim = c(-1,1) )
#limits (red)
abline( v = 0 , col = "red" , lwd = 1 , lty = 2 )
abline( v = 1 , col = "red" , lwd = 1 , lty = 2 )
#truncated mean (green)
abline( v = mean( x[ !(x<0|x>1)] ) , col = "green" , lty = 2 , lwd = 1 )
#true mean (blue)
abline( v = 0.1 , col = "blue" , lty = 1 , lwd = 1 )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I want to however end up with a vector of random numbers with the same mean value as given as input. Like if I wanted to simulate a population with the mean 0.1, after the simulation, truncation or not I still expect a mean value of 0,1, otherwise my simulation is screwed :-/

Comment: @XavierPrudent Skew your expected mean until you get out a desired mean. I think that's the only way to go here.

Comment: It sound then like there is no magic package that skews that mean automatically, I will look further in that direction, thanks Roman and Simon

Comment: Also bear in mind that your sample's standard deviation will not match your nominal value.  If you want to ensure that is matched, you will also need to rescale your data.  There are expressions for the moments of the truncated distribution in terms of the boundaries and nominal values - inverting these would be a formal way of solving your problem.

Comment: Seems like the `beta` distribution would be appropriate for you. Try `?rbeta`